# не отображается png на сайте

Tags: php

не понимаю почему не отображается после загрузки изображение в формате png с прозрачным фоном. с изображениями jpg все отлично! после нажатия на кнопку изображение проходит через следующий код:

```
function ValidOneImage ($file_array = array(), $folder) {
        //$error = array();

        $blacklist = array(".php", ".phtml", ".php3", ".php4", ".html", ".htm", ".txt", ".zip", ".rar");
        foreach ($blacklist as $item) {
            if(preg_match("/$item\$/i", $file_array['name'])) return 'Error image format';
        }

        $type = $file_array['type'];
        $size = $file_array['size'];

        if (($type != "image/jpg") && ($type != "image/jpeg") && ($type != "image/png")) return 'Error image type';
        if ($size > 20480000) return 'Error image size';

        if (!file_exists("images/".$folder."/")) mkdir("images/".$folder."/");

        $images = "images/".$folder."/".$file_array['name'];
        if(move_uploaded_file($file_array['tmp_name'], $images)){
            $this->resize_photo("images/".$folder."/", $file_array['name'], $file_array['size'], $file_array['type'], $file_array['tmp_name']);
        }

        return $images;
    }

function resize_photo($path,$filename,$filesize,$type,$tmp_name){
        // Проверяем, существует ли файл: если существует - ресайзим его
        if(file_exists($path.$filename))
        {                
            $height = 480; //параметр высоты превью
            $width = 640; //параметр ширины превью
            $rgb = 0xffffff; //цвет заливки несоответствия 0xFFFFFF - белый
            $size = getimagesize($path.$filename);//узнаем размеры картинки (дает нам масcив size)
            //определяем тип файла
            $format = strtolower(substr($size['mime'], strpos($size['mime'], '/')+1));
            $icfunc = "imagecreatefrom" . $format;   //определение функции соответственно типу файла

            //если нет такой функции прекращаем работу скрипта
            if (!function_exists($icfunc)) return false; 
            $x_ratio = $width / $size[0]; //пропорция ширины будущего превью
            $y_ratio = $height / $size[1]; //пропорция высоты будущего превью
            $ratio       = min($x_ratio, $y_ratio);
            $use_x_ratio = ($x_ratio == $ratio); //соотношения ширины к высоте
            $new_width   = $use_x_ratio  ? $width  : floor($size[0] * $ratio); //ширина превью 
            $new_height  = !$use_x_ratio ? $height : floor($size[1] * $ratio); //высота превью
            //расхождение с заданными параметрами по ширине
            $new_left    = $use_x_ratio  ? 0 : floor(($width - $new_width) / 2);
            //расхождение с заданными параметрами по высоте
            $new_top     = !$use_x_ratio ? 0 : floor(($height - $new_height) / 2);
            //создаем вспомогательное изображение пропорциональное превью
            $img = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
            imagefill($img, 0, 0, $rgb); //заливаем его…
            $photo = $icfunc($path.$filename); //достаем наш исходник

            imagecopyresampled($img, $photo, $new_left, $new_top, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $size[0], $size[1]); //копируем на него нашу превью с учетом расхождений       

            //$func = 'image'.$format;
            switch($type) {
                case 'gif':
                    imagegif($img, $path.$filename); // параметр качества не предусмотрен
                    break;
                case 'jpg':
                    imagejpeg($img, $path.$filename, 45); // диапазон значений параметра $quality = 0...100, 100 = максимальное качество картинки
                    break;
                case 'png':
                    imagepng($image, $filename, 5);
            }
            //$func($img, $path.$filename, $quality, PNG_NO_FILTER); //сохраняем результат (превью картинки)
            // Очищаем память после выполнения скрипта
            imagedestroy($img);
            imagedestroy($photo);
        }
    }
```

при этом ошибок нет никаких!
после загрузки файл на сервере есть! и ссылка в html код выводится верная, а изображение нет, не понимаю почему

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте перейти по ссылке на изображение и посмотреть отобразится ли оно в браузере, если нет, то вероятно сервер не отдает png